# How do I get a Fontawesome version 5 icon inside an input element?

Tags: css, input, font-awesome-5

Since I use Font Awesome version 5 I have a problem with icons inside an input element. It shows only outside the input text element.

[Image of what I mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jlm6M.gif)
I want the icon INSIDE the input type text field.

The code:

```css
.calendar-label::after {
    content: "\f073";
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Solid";
   display: none;
   position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<head>

<script>
  FontAwesomeConfig = { searchPseudoElements: true };
</script>

<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/all.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<label class="calendar-label">
   <input type="text" name="datum">
</label>

</body>
```

Comment: as i told you before, use negative margin and you will get it inside ... or refer to the other question for more ways https://jsfiddle.net/2bzg1Lwj/1/

Comment: Negative margin is not the solution when the input gets smaller. And it is not a duplicate of existing questions because version 5 of fontawesome icons is totaly different then earlier versions. Thats the problem.

Comment: show me how negative margin aren't solution when input get smaller

Comment: I think it works! Thanks for your respons.